# Plot entropy triangle

Tags: r, matlab, plot

I'd like to plot a ternary triangle plot that is filled with the result of a function f1(a,b,c) where a,b,c denote the three input variables. A solution in R or Matlab would be great. There are triangle plot libraries but I couldn't find a parameter that allows me to specify a costume function f1. [These](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~cis520/wiki/uploads/Lectures/tri_entropy_small.png) guys posted one for entropy. Any suggestions welcome!

Durin

Comment: What have you already tried? What specific problems occured?

Comment: Tried the R package "ggtern" and looked for a similar function in Matlab. I know how to plot a triangle plot but I don't know how to fill it. Would expect something like: 

  plot.triangle(a,b,c,fill=function(a,b,c){ return sum(a,b,c)})

However, I haven't found it yet.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2299-alchemyst-ternplot In Matlab  this is the only way to go (i think). tts not complete but it may work for you